# Injectivity of a transformation on vector spaces over the same field ex

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V,W be the vector spaces over a field K, and assume that $\dim V=\dim W$. Let $F:V\to W$ be a linear map. If $F$ is surjective, prove that $F$ is an >isomorphism.

I know I need to prove that F is injective but for that I need to prove Kernel of $F$ is 0. I think I need to use the field K but I do not know how.

**Question**: How can I prove this statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is false for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: The claim is false. Let $K=\Bbb R$,  $V=W=K[X]$ be the sapce of polynoials in one variable $X$ with real coefficients, and let $F$ be formal differentiation. Then $F$ is surjective, but not injective.

Comment: I think the OP means that $\dim V=\dim W<\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This theorem only holds for finite dimensional vector spaces.

Recall the identity $$\dim(ker (f)) + \dim (Im(f)) = dim(V)$$ with $V$ the domain of the linear mapping $f$

If $F$ is surjective, we have $W = Im(F)$. Hence,

$dim(ker(T)) + dim(W) = dim(V) \Rightarrow dim(ker(T)) = 0 \Rightarrow ker(T) = \{0\} \Rightarrow T$ injective

Since $T$ is surjective and injective, $T$ is an isomorphism $\triangle$

Comment: How do you know $\dim(W)=\dim(V)$?

Comment: Look at the problem statement. That's given.

Comment: It says 'assume dim(V) = dim(W)'

Comment: Right! I am sorry. But just another question: How do you know $W=Im(F)$? If it is surjective it could $\dim(w)\geqslant \dim(Im(F))$, right?

Comment: If I have a function $T: V \to W$. If T is surjective, for any element in W, we can find an element in the domain that gets mapped to that particular element of W. This means $W = Im(T) = \{T(v) | v \in V\}$ right?

Comment: But that is also true if $\dim(w)\geqslant \dim(Im(F))$, right?

Comment: Yes, because $Im(F)$ is a subspace of $W$, the codomain of F. (so it must have a smaller dimension)

Comment: So how can you state the following "If $F$ is surjective, we have $W=Im(F)$"?

Comment: Define surjectivity. I don't know what definition you are using. Then, I'll edit my answer to show that this is true.

Comment: I am reading it again and you are right! Thanks for the attention!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is a finite dimensional space, let dim$V=$dim$W=n$. Let's take $B={\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}}$ base of $V$ and $C=\{{w_1,\dots,w_n\}}$ base of $W$.

If the two spaces have dimension $n$, by passing at the coordinates we know that $V \simeq \mathbb{K}^n$. We also have that $W \simeq \mathbb{K}^n$. As we know that composition of isomorphisms is an isomorphism, we have that: $$V \simeq \mathbb{K}^n \simeq W$$ from which we have the thesis.

**Coordinates**:
Taken a base of your vector space, $B=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ you can write every vector of $V$ as $v=a_1v_1+ \dots+a_nv_n$. Let's consider the map $$\phi:V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$$
$$\phi(v) = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}$$

This is called a coordinate passage. You can easily see that this is an isomorphism, so you can conclude as above.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not understanding how you proved F to be injective.

Comment: Added a comment on coordinate passage, hoping that you can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

use this for vector spaces with finite dimensions: $dimV=dim(imF)+dim(kerF)$. If $F$ is surjective, $dim(imF)=dim W=dimV$ and it follows that $ker(F)= \{0\}$, so $F$ is also injective and hence an isomorphism